Can't load System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
.net 6.0 project, it throw the exception can't find a dll version 6.
this is the error:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
)
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor(Uri uri)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.HttpRequestCreator.Create(Uri Uri)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   at Amazon.S3.Util.AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExistAsync(IAmazonS3 s3Client, String bucketName)

csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.8.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Datadog.Trace" Version="2.55.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FFMpegCore" Version="4.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="libphonenumber-csharp" Version="8.13.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.17.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xabe.FFmpeg" Version="5.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Confluent.Kafka" Version="1.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


I have tried:

clean rebuild
clean nuget cache


Going by the Callstack, are you using WebRequest directly or is it being used in one of your dependencies? If directly, try using HttpClient instead as WebRequest is now deprecated.

It's called by Amazon S3. DoesS3BucketExistAsync
